# ReactiveUI - ViewCell Binding

Tags: xamarin.forms, reactiveui

I'm trying to reproduce the [101 example](https://docs.reactiveui.net/en/getting-started/example.html) of ReactiveUI and adapt it to  `Xamarin Forms`.

I use a custom `ViewCell` but cannot bind it the `ReactiveUI` way:

```
public partial class FlickrPhotoCell : ViewCell, IViewFor<FlickrPhotoModel>
{
    public FlickrPhotoCell()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.Bind(ViewModel, vm => vm.Title, v => v.TitleLabel.Text);
        this.Bind(ViewModel, vm => vm.Description, v => v.DescriptionLabel.Text);
        this.Bind(ViewModel, vm => vm.Url, v => v.UrlImage.Source, null, new CustomConverter());
    }

    //The rest of the code below is plumbing:

    public static readonly BindableProperty ViewModelProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(ViewModel), typeof(FlickrPhotoModel), typeof(FlickrPhotoCell));

    public FlickrPhotoModel ViewModel
    {
        get { return (FlickrPhotoModel)GetValue(ViewModelProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ViewModelProperty, value); }
    }

    object IViewFor.ViewModel
    {
        get { return ViewModel; }
        set { ViewModel = (FlickrPhotoModel)value; }
    }
}
```

Whereas it works fine if I do it the usual `Xamarin Forms` way:

```
public FlickrPhotoCell()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        TitleLabel.SetBinding<FlickrPhotoModel>(Label.TextProperty, x => x.Title);
        DescriptionLabel.SetBinding<FlickrPhotoModel>(Label.TextProperty, x => x.Description);
        UrlImage.SetBinding<FlickrPhotoModel>(Image.SourceProperty, x => x.Url);
    }
```

Comment: Can you please add your View Xaml, especially the one with the ListView?

Comment: One difference I think is that the Xamarin Forms way is using the BindingContext whereas the ReactiveUI way is using purely the ViewModel. So my first guess would be that the ViewModel property isn't getting set. Maybe try binding the BindingContext to the ViewModel? Or override OnBindingContext Changed and set the ViewModel there just to see if that works

Comment: That sounds like a sensible comment. I'll try now !

Comment: @ShaneNeuville That was it. Well spotted. Make it an answer and I'll mark it as correct.

Comment: Awesome :-) Yea it's not obvious at first that RxUI's binding is working sort of independently of Xamarin's BindingContext.  I find that I just mix and match what I use based on the situation.  For the most part though I trust in the RxUI bindings also you don't have to have a "BindableProperty" at the other end when doing OneWays which I find very useful. I get really lazy about creating BindableProperties :-p

Comment: Too bad I can't reuse Xamarin Forms converters directly though :-(

Comment: I think the idea is to make the RxUI binding engine as independent of Xamarin Forms as possible so that it's more resilient from breaking changes. For things like that usually I just move the logic of the converter to a reusable place and then I can call that from both places. And to be honest I way prefer just using RxUI Bindings when I have to do converter stuff because just specifying those conversions on an inline function is a lot nicer then the ceremony of a converter :-) IMHO.  Plus then it's all just in one place and easy follow.

Comment: The problem of having to manually assign to `ViewModel` has annoyed me many a time too, so I've created an issue to address this: https://github.com/reactiveui/ReactiveUI/issues/1256

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One difference I think is that the Xamarin Forms way is using the BindingContext whereas the ReactiveUI way is using purely the ViewModel. So my first guess would be that the ViewModel property isn't getting set. Maybe try binding the BindingContext to the ViewModel? Or override OnBindingContext Changed and set the ViewModel there just to see if that works